# NET MVC, EF 6: database login failed for user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I´m using `EF 6 code first` and was able to connect to the database to create the tables using

```
public DbSet<Entity> TableName { get; set; }
```

The user in `SQL Server Management Studio` is created and I can log in with it.
My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db_databasename;User Id=Administrator;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I´m then trying to add entities to a table, which results in the login error mentioned below:

```
Article article = new Article();
... add some property
context.Articles.Add(article);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Using `context.Database.Connection.Open();` leads to the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Error on login for user DOMAIN\PC-Name
```

Commenting the above leads to the following error:

```
The underlying provider failed on open
```

My context constructor looks like this:

```
public MyAppContext() : base("db_databasename") 
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyAppContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyAppContext>());
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyAppContext, Project.Migrations.Configuration>("MyConnectionString"));
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

DB Migrations are working fine!
So the connection string seems to work, but what else may cause this error?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
Integrated Security=False
```

leads to the same behavior

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public MyAppContext() : base("MyConnectionString")`?

Comment: No: string nameOrConnectionstring

Comment: So, what is `"db_databasename"`? is it the name of the connection string in the config? The config that you showed us have a connection string having name = `"MyConnectionString"`.

Comment: "string nameOrConnectionstring": name isn't a database name but connection string name in the web.config ("MyConnectionString" in your case)

Comment: OMG! Sorry guys, inserting the connection string name to the constructor solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyAppContext() : base("name=MyConnectionString") //-> change ctor like this
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyAppContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyAppContext>());
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyAppContext, Project.Migrations.Configuration>("MyConnectionString"));
}
```